# Image src (via javascript) inconsistency between chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, image, request, frontend, client-side

Heya, so I'm running into a weird bug/edgecase. Check out the following code:

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTIxOTAxNTc4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg1NzQyMQ@@._V1._SX97_SY140_.jpg';
console.log(i.width);
```

This works fine in chrome (as it's referring to a real image), but fails in FF. Thought it may have to do with the 'at' signs or the double extension (eg. '._V1._SX97_SY140_.jpg'), but don't really know.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does firebug say? Any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: I would bet you just need to url encode the path.

Comment: not in the console, but strangely, i'm getting a 403 returned when i look in the net panel. thoughts?

Comment: @Hogan no tried that. looks like it's a server rejection issue...

Comment: @onassar - Try the URL directly on both browsers and trace sniff network traffic to see the differences (if any).

Comment: that works. looks like it has to do with a certain header being requested in ff but not in chrome. im guessing it's the referer header. will run more tests. they might be rejecting any requests that pass along a referer header (which doesn't get sent when you request it directly).

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind, that the image is loaded asynchronously. You need to assign a event handler for the load event of the image and get the width there:

```
var i = new Image();
i.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.width);
}
i.src = 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTIxOTAxNTc4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg1NzQyMQ@@._V1._SX97_SY140_.jpg';
```

Comment: ya, forgot to put that in my code, but that doesn't seem to help the issue of a 403 being returned since there are extra headers in the request in ff that imdb's servers dont like, that chrome doesn't appear to send along.

Comment: @onassar: that's probably a good detail to include in the question itself.

Comment: What are the extra headers that imdb does not like?

Answer (score 0):

A 403 response header means **Forbidden** ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)), that you are not allowed to access the resource.

imdb.com might be doing this to prevent hotlinking of their images in other sites.